# Discord bot JDA connect user to channel

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want create bot with join all online users to voice channel. I can get users but I can't connect them to channel. I saw many similar questions but all solutions don't work, does discord disabled this feature? Does net.dv8tion JDA end support this?

Comment: Discord does not allow you to arbitrarily force users into a voice connection. That would be an excessively annoying feature.

Comment: Even switch channel from A to B?

Answer (score 0):

No, discord does not support this feature. But, you can get every active member that is in a voice channel and move them into one specific channel.